# Media Queries - Generic Responsive Templates

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to create generic responsive templates, 
which media-queries 
i have to use if i want to detect all the devices sizes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check this [Common CSS Media Queries Break Points](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2013/06/responsive-media-queries-css.html)

```
/*------------------------------------------
  Responsive Grid Media Queries - 1280, 1024, 768, 480
   1280-1024   - desktop (default grid)
   1024-768    - tablet landscape
   768-480     - tablet 
   480-less    - phone landscape & smaller
--------------------------------------------*/
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1280px) { }

@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) { }

@media all and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) { }

@media all and (max-width: 480px) { }


/* Portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) { /* Portrait styles here */ }
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) { /* Landscape styles here */ }


/* CSS for iPhone, iPad, and Retina Displays */

/* Non-Retina */
@media screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
}

/* Retina */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
}

/* iPhone Portrait */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation:portrait) {
} 

/* iPhone Landscape */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation:landscape) {
}

/* iPad Portrait */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (orientation:portrait) {
}

/* iPad Landscape */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (orientation:landscape) {
}
```

Comment: I am using the above css but the buttons on my website are not following the style. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle for better idea.

Comment: I did some search yesterday and I found that the asp.net button dont obey it. Any suggestions or should I go ahead with bootstrap 3? Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I highly recomend using Bootstrap. Faster development. Also documentation is very complete.
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

As for your question, you have this example:

```
/*Anything outside of media queries is for MOBILE
  This is Mobile first approach.
*/

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if these websites help you out:

http://24ways.org/2011/conditional-loading-for-responsive-designs/

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/